# how to extract day in char in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i would like to extract the day in char in the following code:

```
SELECT DN_DETAILS.DN,DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY,
       DN_WORKING_HOURS.BEGIN_HOUR,
       DN_WORKING_HOURS.END_HOUR 
FROM DN_DETAILS 
  JOIN DN_WORKING_HOURS ON DN_DETAILS.DN=DN_WORKING_HOURS.DN
WHERE DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY = (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Day') FROM DUAL);
```

the col DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY has days in the form 'Sunday','Monday' etc...

whats wrong with this:

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Day') FROM DUAL)
```

don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Are you working in the same language? What does `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Day') FROM DUAL` actually show you in the session you're running the whole query? What data type is the `DAY` column?

Comment: DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY is a varchar2?

Comment: the day col is in CHAR,

Comment: yes its in varchar

Comment: The `select` is useless `DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Day')` is enough. But: `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Day')` seems an extremely complicated way of writing `'Mon'`

Comment: yes i tried without the select but still it's the same...

Comment: TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Day') should be 'Monday'

Comment: sorry I think the data model is at fault here; that needs to be fixed imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `Day` format element is padded to the length of the longest day name in your date language; which in English is Wednesday at 9 characters. You can see the padding with:

```
select '<'|| to_char(sysdate + level, 'Day') ||'>' from dual connect by level <= 7;

'<'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+LEVEL,'DAY')||'>'
--------------------------------------
<Thursday >
<Friday   >
<Saturday >
<Sunday   >
<Monday   >
<Tuesday  >
<Wednesday>
```

You can add the [FM format model modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) to suppress that padding:

```
select '<'|| to_char(sysdate + level, 'FMDay') ||'>' from dual connect by level <= 7;

'<'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+LEVEL,'FMDAY')||'
--------------------------------------
<Thursday>
<Friday>
<Saturday>
<Sunday>
<Monday>
<Tuesday>
<Wednesday>
```

So, assuming your table's `Day` column is `varchar2` and not padded too, your subquery needs to be:

```
(SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'FMDay') FROM DUAL)
```

... or as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned do the same thing without a subquery:

```
...
WHERE DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'FMDay');
```

Bear in mind that day names are NLS-dependent so if this might ever be run in a non-English environment you could make it safer with:

```
...
WHERE DN_WORKING_HOURS.DAY = TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('03/10/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'FMDay',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
```